# Application Insights reporting a failure but without logs

Tags: azure-application-insights

Application Insights is reporting an exception, I receive an email alert about the error (that I have setup), but when searching for it, I only see the peak in the "Failure" tabs.

It does not show in the "Logs => Exceptions" nor "Transaction Search".
I have set the correct Date Range.

How can I find this exception? why is it triggered?
This is not happening with all exceptions.

[image: Exception]

Comment: what's your alert?

Comment: @IvanYang Metric Name: Http5xx

Comment: please check in the logs -> requests table, and see if there are any error related to 5xx.

Comment: Indeed they show up in the request table. I have to dig more because there is nothing correlated to this error. Thanks. Surprising they don't show up in this Overall spot.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [this limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-exceptions#web-api) for web api / mvc:

> All exceptions handled by application still need to be tracked
> manually. Unhandled exceptions originating from controllers typically
> result in 500 "Internal Server Error" response. If such response is
> manually constructed as a result of handled exception (or no exception
> at all) it is tracked in a corresponding request telemetry with
> ResultCode 500, however Application Insights SDK is unable to track
> corresponding exception.

Comment: Do you have an idea why it's showing in the graph but not the tables? This unfortunately makes it quite confusing. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @jsgoupil, yes, it's confusing. I'm not sure about it, maybe in the graph, it uses some api directly fetch the request error from requests table. But in the tables(the table in your screenshot), the ai-sdk is responsible for it then as per the doc in my answer, this kind of error cannot be tracked? Just a guess.